# uninitialized constant Capybara (NameError) running RoR tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

in my spec_helper.rb, I have:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
```

Then I am running:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

******-C02MGBVJFD57:myapp ********$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
/Users/*********/workspace/myapp/spec/spec_helper.rb:18:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Capybara (NameError)
```

Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to inlcude `capybara` gem.

You can add this in your Gemfile and run `bundle install`.

```
gem 'capybara'
```

After that include below in your helper file:

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
```